# Plotting parametric equations in gnuplot

Tags: math-software, parametric

I am trying to plot the following parametric equation in gnuplot:

`fx(t) = -35*cos(t) + 65*cos(-.35*t)`

`fy(t) = -35*sin(t) - 65*sin(-.35*t)`

I am not using much more code than pasted above. The result is fairly ugly.It is very angular, and obviously there must be some command to smooth it out.

I have tried to use commands like `smooth cspline` and `smooth bezier` to no avail.

How do I make a nice smooth graph of this function in gnuplot?

Comment: I cant answer your question; but the graph is quite pretty, as produced by JSXgraph. I'm tempted to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `samples` value typing, for example,

```
set samples 10000
```

Here is the complete command:

```
set parametric
set xrange [-110:110]
set yrange [-110:120]
set trange [0:300]
set samples 10000
plot -35*cos(t)+65*cos(-.35*t),-35*sin(t)-65*sin(-.35*t)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it. I was using the samples with values of 30 or 60. I had no idea I had to go that high. I tried it with 20000, but there was no difference. It would be nice to know  how to make the graph with the smoothest possible lines...it seems that after 10000 it is as smooth as it can get.

Answer (score 0):

This link may help to answer your question
http://nrlug.puhep.res.in/GLUE/Packages/plot/gnuplot/parametric.html